# Set the model depending on what it is expecting in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### The goal

Change the model depending on what it is expecting.

### The problem

I have a method in my `ProductsController`called `Category`. When someone request this method, two things **can** happen: if the parameter passed to the method is different than `Daily-Offers`, then one type of list is passed to View. If the parameter passed to the method is equal to `Daily-Offers`, then another type of list is passed to View.

To better comprehension, see:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Category(string categoryName = null)
{
    int? categoryId = categoryName != "Daily-Offers" ? 
                      Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(categoryName, @"\d+").Value) :
                      (int?)null;

    if (categoryName == "Daily-Offers")
    {
        var productsList = Products.BuildOffersList();
        ViewBag.Title = String.Format("Today's deal: ({0})", DateTime.Now);
        ViewBag.CategoryProductsQuantity = productsList.Count;
        ViewBag.CurrentCategory = "Daily-Offers";
        return View(productsList);
    }
    else if (Regex.Match(categoryName, @"\d+").Success && 
             String.Format("{0}-{1}", 
             categoryId, 
             CommodityHelpers.UppercaseFirst
                (CommodityHelpers.GenerateSlug
                     (Categories.GetDetails((sbyte)categoryId).Category_Name))) 
            == categoryName)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = Categories.GetDetails((sbyte)categoryId).Category_Name;
        ViewBag.CategoryProductsQuantity = 
        Categories.GetDetails((sbyte)categoryId).Category_Products_Quantity;
        ViewBag.CurrentCategory = 
           CommodityHelpers.UppercaseFirst(CommodityHelpers.GenerateSlug
           (Categories.GetDetails((sbyte)categoryId).Category_Name));
        return View(Products.BuildListForHome(categoryId, null));
    }
    else
    {
        return View("404");
    }
}
```

As you can see, the view should be prepared to receive `IList<Offers>` or/and `IList<NormalProducts>` — ***and I do not know how to do this.***

### What I have already tried

Something like this:

```
@model if(IEnumerable<BluMercados.Models.Data.getProductsListForHome_Result>) 
       ?: (IEnumerable<BluMercados.Models.Data.getProductsInOfferList_Result>);
```

But, of course, no success. Just to illustrate.

Comment: Is this problem not something solved by creating two different views and then calling View("ViewName", model)?

Comment: @Rossisdead Yes, you are right. The point is: the UI is very similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A view should really only have one model, so trying to make a view consume two different models, while doable, shouldn't be done.

Instead, you can create different views.  Say you create a new view for DailyOffers, which takes `IEnumerable<Offers>` as its model.

You can then user an overload of View() to specify which view to return:

```
return View("DailyOffers", productsList);
```

However, instead of doing this, would it make more sense to redirect to a different action in the case of DailyOffers?  So, you have a new action:

```
public ActionResult DailyOffers(...)
```

and instead of `return View(productsList)` you do:

```
return RedirectToAction("DailyOffers");
```

This all assumes that the models are sufficiently different from one another.  If they are similar, using the Interface solution as suggested by p.s.w.g. would make more sense.

Comment: +1 I hadn't considered using different actions, but that's a good solution, too.

Comment: When I access `Categories/Daily-Offers` this will be redirect to `Products/DailyOffers` and I do not want this. I already have tried to change this in my route configuration file, but results in an endless loop.

Comment: You can use another overload of RedirectToAction to ensure you remain in the Categories controller:  `return RedirectToAction("DailyOffers", "Categories")`

Comment: Partially worked, @MatthewJones. I want to keep the same name `Daily-Offers`.

Comment: In that case, decorate the action with `[ActionName("Daily-Offers")]` and call the action DailyOffers.  Then, when redirecting, use `RedirectToAction("Daily-Offers", "Categories")`.

Comment: @MatthewJones I have already tried this. The result? Endless loop.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do that, and even if you could, it wouldn't be good practice. If the view for each model is very similar, I'd recommend creating an common interface for `Offers` and `NormalProducts`

```
public interface IProduct
{
    // common properties ...
}

public class Offer : IProduct
{
    // ...
}

public class NormalProduct : IProduct
{
    // ...
}
```

And then in your view use

```
@model IEnumerable<IProduct>
```

If your view for each model is significantly different, I'd strongly recommend splitting these into different views, and deciding between them in controller:

```
if (categoryName == "Daily-Offers")
{
    ...
    return View("Category_Offers", productsList);
}
else if (...)
{
    ...
    return View("Category_NormalProducts", Products.BuildListForHome(categoryId, null));
}
```

And then in your view use

```
// Category_Offers.cshtml
@model IEnumerable<Offer>

// Category_NormalProducts.cshtml
@model IEnumerable<NormalProduct>
```